# How can i get sum of each elements in tuple Python

Tags: python, sum, tuples

For example i have a tuple

```
t = ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1))
```

How can i get sum of all this elements with only one loop

I would like to get
`6`

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` with `sum`, and get the `sum` of the result:

```
sum(map(sum, t))
# 6
```

---

Or if you prefer it with a for loop:

```
res = 0
for i in t:
    res += sum(i)

print(res)
# 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple iteration (works in python3.8, I assume it works on older versions as well).

```py
t = ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)) 
sum_tuples = 0
for a,b in t:
    sum_tuples += a # First element
    sum_tuples += b # Second Element

print(sum_tuples) # prints 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> t = ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)) 
>>> sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop tuple to sum all. This code is long but it can sum `tuple` in `tuple`.

```py
t = ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1))
# Tuple in tuple:
t = ((1, 1, (1, 1, (1, 1))))

def getsum(var, current = 0):
    result = current
    if type(var) == tuple:
        for i in range(len(var)):
            x = var[i]
            result = getsum(x, result)
    else:
        result += var
    return result

print(getsum(t))
```